# Where to Store Images for Web Application in WebSphere

Tags: image, web-applications, websphere

I have a store front web application installed in WebSphere.  Where is the best place to store the item images that will be displayed in the HTML pages?  I don't want to store them in the EAR file because it makes the EAR file very large.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend storing them somewhere for the web server or even a proxy server to serve. Using some kind of alias to static content, rather than having WebSphere serve them at all.